# Show a picture in the gallery on the app in Android

Tags: android, gallery, multimedia

I am writing an app in which the user will click on a button in the app, the gallery will pop up, the user will select an image from the gallery and the selected image is supposed to be shown in the imageView that I placed on the screen. When I click the button the gallery pops up, I select an image but for some reason that image doesn't show up on my app screen. Thank you very much for your help. I added only two permissions as follows:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

And here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showPicture(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            Bitmap selectedImage = null;

            try{
                selectedImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), photoUri);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I tried the code given in the answer, but I get the following errors in my stack trace. Only RuntimeExceptions are shown for brevity:

```
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/46 }} to activity {cs193a.stanford.edu.testproject/cs193a.stanford.edu.testproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/46 from pid=2754, uid=10059 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()

                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media/46 from pid=2754, uid=10059 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

The only line of code that seems to be problematic in my code is again the line where the Cursor is declared. Thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

To open gallery

```
Intent i = new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

To get back the result :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);   

        switch(requestCode) {  
        case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:  
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)  
            {  
                Uri uri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();  
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};  

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);  
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);  
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);  
                cursor.close();
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagev);
               im.setImageBitmap(image);
            }  
        }  
    }
```

Edit: Please try this now

Comment: I tried the above code, but my app crashes when I use it. It seems like there's a problem with the line:                                                                 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                          filePathColumn, null, null, null);

Comment: Are you running on Marshamllow?

Comment: Di you implement the runtime permission model ?

Comment: No I am using Android Studio and its native emulator, and no I did not implement anything more than the things I have posted above.

Comment: Emulator android api level?

Comment: try this code with real device below 6.0 and for 6.0 and above forst implement runtime permission and run the code

Comment: Still couldn't figure out a solution. Please post an answer if you find one.